# Dividing steps in Form Wizard

Tags: website-design, forms, design, users, ux-designer

I have this category input in my form. If a category is not found on the list the user would need to create a new one obviously.

If they would need to create a new, there's 2 options: Category or Subcategory.

Upon selecting which one, they will be presented with a form that corresponds to what they selected.

After done selecting (if it's on the list) or creating a new category, they will need to fill up the attributes of that category.

For example if the category is medicine, the attributes is Dosage.

Currently in my form i have this steps:

- Basic Info step - all inputs the doesn't depend on another input
- Category creation step - Two labels that describes how users will select which one to choose
- Category form step - The form itself on creating new category

Form will proceed to step 2/3 only if the checkbox on 1st step that has a label of "Category not listed?" is checked.

Making an "Attributes Step" seems like a bad idea cause, what if the attributes needed is only one? The step page seems like empty

I am thinking if I should just make the form 1-step only and the "Category Creating" a 2-step wizard inside a Modal.

And just show the attributes by appending on the same page also after selecting a category... well cause it depends on what category it is.

-- EDIT --

Hmm, re-read my post and saw that it has no question hahaha

Uhm, this seems to be more like "An input that is dependent from the previous input". How do you address this?

Answer (score 1):

The wizard approach will not work here because the steps are not linear and depends on user's input to "trigger" the additional step.

The modal approach would interrupt the flow because after user "Submit" the form , the additional modal would require user fill in more input then "Submit" again to finally complete the whole process. This might even cause some confusion.

The single page form approach would be better (if the additional required attributes are short)

1. Chunk the form into smaller bits
2. In the Category section: provide dropdown selection, in the dropdown list, include "New Category"
3. Additional fields appear when user select "Add New Category"
4. User fill in the additional fields.
   [image]
5. User continue to finish the form